# Copying specific elements of array to another array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to copy the Right portion of frame data. The image below could be useful. Data is in single array form.

[image: Picture]

I want to get single array right column of data frame. 
I am getting "Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000`". I am not sure what's wrong.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    int height=10;
    int width = 100;
    int data[]= new int [height*width];
    int multipiler=0;
    int counter =1;
    int hwAssistWidth=5;
    int hwData[] = new int[hwAssistWidth*height];
    int countTheFrame = 0;
    int countTheFrame1 = 0;
    int sourceArray;

    for(int i=0; i<hwAssistWidth*height; i++){
            sourceArray = ((width-hwAssistWidth)+width*multipiler)+counter++;
            hwData[i] = data[sourceArray];


          if (counter==hwAssistWidth+1){
              counter =1;
              multipiler++;
              if(multipiler==height){
                  break;

              }

          }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you debug your program?

Comment: Yes, I did. Please ignore the values inside data array.

Comment: Because your index is out of array data.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine, Thank you for comment. could you please share the solution approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
sourceArray = ((width-hwAssistWidth)+width*multipiler)+counter++;
```

sets the value of sourceArray to 1000 on the final iteration of the for loop.  You then try to access element 1000 of the data array

```
hwData[i] = data[sourceArray];
```

However the data array only has 1000 elements

```
int height=10;
int width = 100;
int data[]= new int [height*width];
```

So the largest index is only 999, which is why you get the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception.  Fix your loop so that the value of sourceArray is never greater than 999.

Comment: Thank you @JoshuaNewHouse. it worked

Comment: No problem.  If this answers your question then you should mark it as answered.